# Accordion in a modal

Tags: jquery, popup, accordion

[This](http://ccs.dev2.mtinc.net/?p=bases) works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer. Click one of the images and the pop up happens.

Inside most of the pop ups is an accordion and it doesn't work.

```
$('#Dynamic #accordion li').children('span').hide();
    $('#Dynamic #accordion li').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#Dynamic #accordion li').children('span').slideUp(0);
        $('#Dynamic #accordion li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('rel')!='') {
                $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('idle');
            }
        });

        $(this).children('span').slideDown(0);
        $(this).removeClass('idle').addClass('over');       

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Seems your hiding the elements before they are loaded into the DOM? Isn't the modal content loaded in after pageload?

Comment: well when the modal content is loaded it brings in the script from about with it. it should be loaded with the content and not with the original page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using dependency on your loads like this:

```
$('#result').load('MODALCONTENTFILE.html', function() {
      $('#result').load('ACCORDIAN.html');
});
```

---

You are loading the content after the DOM has been loaded. So you load the content in after the hide() command has been called.

This works flawless in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/JVtyv/11/

Comment: which IE? i guess i never specified cause it doesn't work in 8 here. or 7 i believe... gosh i hate ie lol

Comment: The example works fine on my IE when i chose IE8/IE7 standard.

Comment: just copied over, and added the JS from accordian :)

Comment: yeah thats the issue though...
it works fine alone. but when its loaded into the modal, it doesn't work in IE. i have the accordion on the contact page and i know it works fine alone. idk why its not working in the pop up.

Comment: Because you say HIDE ACCORDIAN -> LOAD MODAL ... then it can't hide something thats not loaded yet. Try calling `$('#Dynamic #accordion li').children('span').hide();` inside the modal :)

Comment: i just added it outside of the modal for testing

Comment: there are two files that get loaded when the modal is activated. One is the js for the accordion and the other is the content that fills the modal. so both the content and the js that hides the accordion elements are loaded 
`$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
$('#modalJquery').load('templates/public/modal-accordion.html');      
 $("#Dynamic").load('templates/public/' + id + '.html');`

Comment: Yes exactly. You are loading the accordian BEFORE the modal content...!

Comment: can you remove that link pls?
is there an order of operations that i can do in my .load() to load the content then the js?